# static css is not fetching style in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

when i am trying to load my style sheet from static it not fetch and implement the css to my project

my folder as goes onething\home\static\home 
in home i'm having style.css[u can check folder structure in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RJGH.png)

here is my base.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}One Thing{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.pink-purple.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

and my setting as go

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    ]
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but my css stylesheet is not loading. please help me where i did mistake

Comment: it working, just cleared the cache of the browser by CRLT + SHIFT + R

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, add these lines under your `STATIC_URL`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
```

Ensure that your static folder is inside your **project folder**.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed

Comment: Move your static folder up one level then use my code

Comment: @somasekhar or you can change `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `( os.path.join('home/static'), )`

Comment: i tried that, no changes and i tried to move static file but my IDE is not allowing

Comment: Try closing your IDE, moving it in file explorer, then reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

**First** : create `static` folder in this path (tree path):

```
-------manage.py
-------db.sqlite3
-------static #this si your static folder!
-------appfolder
```

**Second** : put you CSS (or JavaScript or an image) in your static folder like this:

```
-----static
---------1.css
---------2.js
```

**Third** : put this at the bottom of your `setting.py` file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**4th** : call your static file in your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src="{% static "1.css" %}"">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src="{% static "1.css" %}"">
```

It should work.

**Note :** use `{% load staticfiles %}` at the start of your file.

Comment: i done same you listed above. only thing i didn't do is static root. i added that but nothing changed. please specify the chance why they happen and give me the steps. Thank you

Comment: What is your django version.{% load staticfiles %}  is diffrent on the old versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **STATICFILES_DIRS** in yoir settings.py inorder to the static files to work. Add this to the end of settings.py

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home/static'), ]
```